# WSO2 Business Process Server (CARBON_HOME issue)

Tags: wso2

I am new to WSO2. According to prerequisites I have created the environment(Done JAVA_HOME & Done Maven Path too),I am getting a message like below. The message is like

```
D:\...\bin>wso2server.bat
CARBON_HOME is set incorrectly or CARBON could not be located. Please set CARBON_HOME.
```

How can I set the CARBON_HOME correctly ?

> ```
> C:\Users\Ganesh>set JAVA_HOME
> JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67
> ```

Comment: basically we don't need to set CARBON_HOME. You can  set CARBON_HOME and see.

Comment: can you post your full stack trace so that it will be easy to sorted out?

Comment: Hi Soorapadman, How to set "set CARBON_HOME "

Comment: have you set your JAVA_HOME correctly? if yes then close BPS and run again and see it should work

Comment: let me know the status

Comment: Yes , along with that I have given maven path too.I run twice & restarts the system & runs it again.

Comment: JAVA_HOME is correct have you added in path variable?

Comment: yes I have checked by "Set JAVA_HOME"

Comment: ok fine set CARBON_HOME=C:\bps\carbon-repo in your environment. just giving you example

Comment: @GaneshSudarsan, What is your OS?

Comment: Check whether the path where BPS is located contain any spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Just download the **wso2ei** file from here

https://github.com/wso2/product-ei/releases/download/v6.4.0-m7/wso2ei-6.4.0-m7.zip

Unzip it

let your path of wso2ei is `D:\WSO2Learning\wso2ei-6.4.0-m7`

Set `variable name` as `CARBON_HOME`

and `variable value` as `D:\WSO2Learning\wso2ei-6.4.0-m7`

Open a new command prompt `D:\WSO2Learning\wso2ei-6.4.0-m7\bin`

then type `integrator.bat` and hit enter.